# Active Admin putting an inputs in an inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm trying to put an ff.inputs in a f.inputs in regards of a double nested object but the ff.inputs doesn't show up. When I put it in a partial it shows up but duplicates the fields.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Form:

```
form do |f|
f.inputs 'Brand Details' do
  f.input :name
  f.input :heritage
end

f.inputs 'Logo', for: [:logo, f.object.logo || Image.new ] do |ff|
  ff.input :file, as: :file, hint: (ff.template.image_tag(ff.object.file.url) if ff.object.file?)
  ff.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, label: 'Remove' unless ff.object.new_record?
end


# render partial: 'banner_form'

f.inputs 'Heritage Banner', for: [:heritage_banner, f.object.heritage_banner || Banner.new] do |hb|
  hb.input :name
  hb.inputs 'Desktop Image*', for: [:desktop_image, hb.object.desktop_image || Image.new ] do |di|
    di.input :file, label: 'Image', as: :file, hint: (di.template.image_tag(di.object.file.url) if di.object.file?)
    di.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, :label => 'Remove' unless di.object.new_record?
  end
  hb.inputs 'Mobile Image*', for: [:mobile_image, hb.object.mobile_image || Image.new ] do |mi|
    mi.input :file, label: 'Image', as: :file, hint: (mi.template.image_tag(mi.object.file.url) if mi.object.file?)
    mi.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, :label => 'Remove' unless mi.object.new_record?
  end
  hb.input :video_url
end

f.inputs 'Header Banner', for: [:header_banner, f.object.header_banner || Banner.new] do |hb|
  hb.input :name
  hb.inputs 'Desktop Image*', for: [:desktop_image, hb.object.desktop_image || Image.new ] do |di|
    di.input :file, label: 'Image', as: :file, hint: (di.template.image_tag(di.object.file.url) if di.object.file?)
    di.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, :label => 'Remove' unless di.object.new_record?
  end
  hb.inputs 'Mobile Image*', for: [:mobile_image, hb.object.mobile_image || Image.new ] do |mi|
    mi.input :file, label: 'Image', as: :file, hint: (mi.template.image_tag(mi.object.file.url) if mi.object.file?)
    mi.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, :label => 'Remove' unless mi.object.new_record?
  end
  hb.input :video_url
end

f.actions
end
```

When using the partial this is it:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @brand] do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs 'Heritage Banner', for: [:heritage_banner, f.object.heritage_banner || Banner.new] do |hb| %>
    <%= hb.input :name %>
    <%= hb.inputs 'Desktop Image*', for: [:desktop_image, hb.object.desktop_image || Image.new ] do |di| %>
        <%= di.input :file, label: 'Image', as: :file, hint: (di.template.image_tag(di.object.file.url) if di.object.file?)  %>
        <%= di.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, :label => 'Remove' unless di.object.new_record?  %>
    <% end %>

    <%= hb.inputs 'Mobile Image*', for: [:mobile_image, hb.object.mobile_image || Image.new ] do |mi| %>
        <%= mi.input :file, label: 'Image', as: :file, hint: (mi.template.image_tag(mi.object.file.url) if mi.object.file?)  %>
        <%=  mi.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, :label => 'Remove' unless mi.object.new_record?  %>
    <% end %>

    <%= hb.input :video_url  %>
<% end %>

<%= f.inputs 'Header Banner', for: [:header_banner, f.object.header_banner || Banner.new] do |hb| %>
    <%= hb.input :name %>
    <%= hb.inputs 'Desktop Image*', for: [:desktop_image, hb.object.desktop_image || Image.new ] do |di| %>
        <%= di.input :file, label: 'Image', as: :file, hint: (di.template.image_tag(di.object.file.url) if di.object.file?)  %>
        <%= di.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, :label => 'Remove' unless di.object.new_record?  %>
    <% end %>

    <%= hb.inputs 'Mobile Image*', for: [:mobile_image, hb.object.mobile_image || Image.new ] do |mi| %>
        <%= mi.input :file, label: 'Image', as: :file, hint: (mi.template.image_tag(mi.object.file.url) if mi.object.file?)  %>
        <%=  mi.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, :label => 'Remove' unless mi.object.new_record?  %>
    <% end %>

    <%= hb.input :video_url  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fix for this was to just put everything in the form partial and just call the partial.

So in active admin I did:

```
form partial: 'form'
```

and in brought in the brand detail fields and logo into the partial.

This also allowed me to call image and banner partials that I could before.

Still let me know if there's a better way to do this.